# Tooltipster prevent overlapping tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltipster

I have a table full of images.
I am using  the `Tooltipster` plugin to display multiple `tooltips` on all four sites of an image on hover.

In the middle of the table it works like expected:
[image]

However, on the left and right side of the table two of the four `tooltips` overlap.

**Left Side:**

[image]

**Right Side:**

[image]

How can i prevent this from happening?

Like force it to show on the left/right side even if it's the end of the table or
displaying both `tooltips` on one side but one after another without overlapping or something else.

Is something like this even possible with `Tooltipster`?

**Update:**

*html:*

```
<div class="Tooltip">
  <img  src="./media/images/test.png" />
</div>

<div class="tooltip_templates" >
    <div  id="tooltip_content_top" >
        text <br>
        text <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip_templates" >
    <div  id="tooltip_content_bottom">
        text <br>
        text <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip_templates" >
    <div  id="tooltip_content_left">
        text <br>
        text <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip_templates" >
    <div  id="tooltip_content_right">
        text <br>
        text <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

*js:*

```
    <script>
        let tooltip= $(".Tooltip");

        tooltip.tooltipster({
            content: $("#tooltip_content_top"),
            contentCloning: true,
            multiple: true,
            side: "top",
        });

        tooltip.tooltipster({
            content: $("#tooltip_content_bottom"),
            contentCloning: true,
            multiple: true,
            side: "bottom",
        });

        tooltip.tooltipster({
            content: $("#tooltip_content_left"),
            contentCloning: true,
            multiple: true,
            side: "left",
        });

        tooltip.tooltipster({
            content: $("#tooltip_content_right"),
            contentCloning: true,
            multiple: true,
            side: "right",
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: try to set 'viewportAware: false'

Comment: You can force sides as per the doc but it's going to be awkward when it's out of screen. I'd write a few lines for custom positioning if I were you, check the doc.

Comment: @ManuelOtto setting `viewportAware: false,` didn`t change anything, i'll try @Louis Ameline's suggestion